# FIWARE - Orion Context Broker as Context Provider

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I'm having a hard time understanding how context providers work in the Orion Context Broker.
I followed the examples in the step-by-step guide written by Jason Fox. However, I still do not exactly get what happens in the background and how the context broker exactly creates the POST from the registration. Here is what I am trying to do:

I do have a WeatherStation that provides sensor data for a neighborhood.

```
{
  "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:WeatherStation:001",
  "type": "Device:WeatherStation",
  "temperature": {
    "type": "Number",
    "value": 20.5,
    "metadata": {}
  },
  "windspeed": {
    "type": "Number",
    "value": 60.0,
    "metadata": {}
  }
}
```

Now I like the WeatherStation to be a context provider for all buildings.

```
{
  "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:building:001",
  "type": "Building"
}
```

Here is the registration that I try to use.

```
{
  "id": null,
  "description": "Random Weather Conditions",
  "provider": {
    "http": {
      "url": "http://localhost:1026/v2"
    },
    "supportedForwardingMode": "all"
  },
  "dataProvided": {
    "entities": [
      {
        "id": "null",
        "idPattern": ".*",
        "type": "Building",
        "typePattern": null
      }
    ],
    "attrs": [
      "temperature",
      "windspeed"
    ],
    "expression": null
  },
  "status": "active",
  "expires": null,
  "forwardingInformation": null
}
```

The context broker accepts both entities and the registration without any error.

Since I have a multi-tenant setup I use one `fiware_service` for the complete neighborhood but every building would later have a seperate `fiware_servicepath`. Hence, the weatherstation has a different servicepath than the building. Although I also tried to put them both on the same path.

For now I used the same headers for all entities.

```
{
  "fiware-service": "filip",
  "fiware-servicepath": "/testing"
}
```

Here is the log of the context broker (version: 3.1.0):

```
INFO@2021-09-23T19:17:17.944Z  logTracing.cpp[212]: Request forwarded (regId: 614cd2b511c25270060d873a): POST http://localhost:1026/v2/op/query, request payload (87 bytes): {"entities":[{"idPattern":".*","type":"Building"}],"attrs":["temperature","windspeed"]}, response payload (2 bytes): [], response code: 200


INFO@2021-09-23T19:17:17.944Z  logTracing.cpp[130]: Request received: POST /v2/op/query?options=normalized%2Ccount&limit=1000, request payload (55 bytes): {"entities": [{"idPattern": ".*", "type": "Building"}]}, response code: 200
```

The log says that it receives the request and forwards it as expected. However, as I understand it this would simply point to the same building entity again. Hence, it is somehow a circular forwarding. I also cannot tell anything about the headers of the request.

I do not understand how the forwarded request from the building can actually query the weather station for information. When I query my building I still only receive the entity with no own properties:

```
{
  "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:building:001",
  "type": "Building"
}
```

I also tried to vary the url of the registration but with no success.

1. Is this scenario actually possible with the current implementation? It would be very useful
2. Is there any example for this including also the headers?

I know that I could simply use reference but that would put more work on the user.

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: You use the id of one single building in your registration ... Don't you want to serve all buildings? Remove the id and just keep the type: Building. And, what exactly goes wrong? Please make sure the registration and the entities are in the same tenant (same fiware-service)

Comment: @kzangeli thank you for the hin. I tried to adjust my payloads according to your comment, but still no luck. I start to believe that my scenario is not possible. :/

Comment: I'm not sure of understanding your setup... are you registering ContextBroker itself as a Context Provider? That's not the usual setup... Context Provider use to be external systems to the ContexBroker. What's the point of registering ContextBroker as "self-provider" if you can query directly for the registered information in ContextBroker itself? I think I'm missing something :)

Answer (score 0):

It is messy, but you could achieve this via a subscription. Hold the weather station as a separate entity in the context broker and poll or push updates into the entity. The subscription would fire whenever the data changes and make two NGSI requests:

- Find all entities which have a Relationship `servicedBy=WeatherStationX`
- Run an upsert on all entities to add a Property to each entity:

```json
{
   "temperature" : {
      "type" : "Property",
      "value" : 7,
      "unitCode": "CEL",
      "observedAt": "XXXXX",
      "providedBy": "WeatherStation1"
   }
}
```

Where `observedAt` comes either from the payload of the weather station or the notification timestamp.

Within the existing IoT Agents, provisioning the [`link`  attribute](https://iotagent-node-lib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-topics/index.html#ngsi-ld-linked-data-support) allows a device to propagate measures to a second entity (e.g. this Thermometer entity is measuring temperature for an associated Building entity)

```json
{
     "entity_type": "Device",
     "resource":    "/iot/d",
     "protocol":    "PDI-IoTA-UltraLight",
..etc
     "attributes": [
        {"object_id": "l", "name": "temperature", "type":"Float",
          "metadata":{
              "unitCode":{"type": "Text", "value" :"CEL"}
          }
        }
     ],
     "static_attributes": [
        {
          "name": "controlledAsset",
          "type": "Relationship",
          "value": "urn:ngsi-ld:Building:001",
          "link": {
             "attributes": ["temperature"],
             "name": "providedBy",
             "type": "Building"
          }
        }
     ]
  }
```

At the moment the logic just links direct one-to-one, but it would be possible to raise a PR to check for an Array and update multiple entities in an upsert - the relevant section of code is [here](https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-node-lib/blob/master/lib/services/ngsi/entities-NGSI-LD.js#L385)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Sorry for coming back to you this late. As I understand you are using NGSI-LD syntax here. My team is still working on NGSIv2. Since we could not yet discover any limits when the used datamodels are predefined in advance. It would be great if registrations an context provider would be explained in more extend in your step by step tutorial. The mechanism is rather complicated. Even between IoT agents and Context Broker there is so much "magic" happening. This is very hard to get and debug.

Comment: Is there also a way to do this in NGSIv2?